Prepared Statement Error when using SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY - expressions must appear in select list
I have a Postgres query in a Prepared statement which I am trying to sort using a :orderBy parameter.
By copying the Order By CASE section into the end of the Select statement. I resolved the error I was getting in pgadmin "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list", the following works for me in pgAdmin:
WITH vars AS (
   SELECT 'title' AS sort_col
-- SELECT 'created_ts' AS sort_col
-- SELECT 'expiry_date' AS sort_col
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ac.*,
    select_translation(ac.title_text_id,'en') AS title,
    CASE vars.sort_col
         WHEN 'title' THEN select_translation(ac.title_text_id,'en')
         WHEN 'created_ts' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.created_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS:MS')
         WHEN 'expiry_date' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.expiry_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         ELSE NULL  -- Or whatever your default should be
    END
FROM vars, action_cards ac      
ORDER BY
    CASE vars.sort_col
         WHEN 'title' THEN select_translation(ac.title_text_id,'en')
         WHEN 'created_ts' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.created_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS:MS')
         WHEN 'expiry_date' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.expiry_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         ELSE NULL
    END

I set the params using:
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            selectAllCardsWithFilterQuery,
            new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("languageCode", languageCode)
                    .addValue("orderBy", orderBy),
            new ActionCardRowMapper()
    );

I am still getting the "SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" error when using a parameter :orderBy (which becomes ?) in the CASE section of the generated prepared statement.
Stacktrace:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT DISTINCT ac.*, select_translation(ac.title_text_id,?) AS title, (CASE (?) WHEN 'title' THEN select_translation(ac.title_text_id,'en') WHEN 'created_ts' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.created_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS:MS') WHEN 'expiry_date' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.expiry_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE NULL END) FROM action_cards ac ORDER BY (CASE (?) WHEN 'title' THEN select_translation(ac.title_text_id,'en') WHEN 'created_ts' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.created_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS:MS') WHEN 'expiry_date' THEN TO_CHAR(ac.expiry_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE NULL END);]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:112)...

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Try ac.created_ts and ac.expiry_date in the select expression, that's the only difference I can see from the order by expression

"when using a parameter (?) in the CASE section" - you probably will have to use the same parameter in both places. ? is positional afaik. Can you please show the entire Java code of how you are constructing the query and setting the params?

You can use parameter in WITH vars AS (  SELECT ? AS sort_col ...

Updated the select ac. values to match, these were not the problem.
Also updated the text, I meant the parameter is :orderBy which in the generated SQL becomes a placeholder of ?

Posted the Java code to my question
